# How to avoid using new twice when registering in Autofac

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I want to register two dependencies using constructors with parameters but I want only to make 'new' on the 'Dependency' class one time.
Instead of this:

```
builder.RegisterInstance(new ClassA(new Dependency())).As<IClassA>().SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterInstance(new ClassB(new Dependency())).AsSelf().SingleInstance();
```

I want something like this:

```
Dependency dependency = new Dependency();
builder.RegisterInstance(new ClassA(dependency)).As<IClassA>().SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterInstance(new ClassB(dependency)).AsSelf().SingleInstance();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you register the dependency first it should automatically get passed to the new instances if they require it.

Assumptions:

```
public class ClassA : IClassA
{
    public ClassA(Dependency dependency)
    {
    }
 }

public class ClassB
{
    public ClassB(Dependency dependency)
    {
    }
 }
```

Then register dependency

```
var dependency = new Dependency();
builder.RegisterInstance(dependency).As<Dependency>();
builder.RegisterType<ClassA>().As<IClassA>().SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterType<ClassB>().AsSelf().SingleInstance();
```

Comment: I tried this approach, but the thing is ClassA has two constructors, with and without parameters. I want to use the constructor that has parameters. If I don't pass the parameter, when I try to resolve ClassA, Autofac uses the constructor with no parameters. To solve that I used `builder.Register(t => new ClassA(t.Resolve<Dependency>())).AsSelf().SingleInstance();` as @Igor answered, but the new is still executing. I need to make a new Dependency just once.

Comment: Register dependency as: builder.RegisterType<Dependency>().AsSelf().SingleInstance().. then it should only new up once

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that there is a reason you want to instantiate the type instead of registering it with Autofac which will do it for you then you should use `Register` instead of `RegisterInstance`.

```
builder.RegisterType<Dependency>().As<Dependency>().SingleInstance();
builder.Register(t => new ClassA(t.Resolve<Dependency>())).As<IClassA>().SingleInstance();
```

You can then use the passed in `IComponentContext` to resolve any required dependencies. Do keep in mind that with `SingleInstance` your instance is only created once so dependencies should be scoped similarly (don't expect a per request dependency to "renew" itself with every call to your singleton).